# Why is my java query causing an error but is fine in Workbench?

Tags: mysql

Hello I am trying to run this query in my program.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM wcrm_Company WHERE CompanyName LIKE "+"%"+search+"%"+" OR PersonName LIKE "+"%"+search+"%"+" OR Country LIKE "+"%"+search+"%";
System.out.println(query);
```

However I get this output and error (LUX is the search term)

```
SELECT * FROM wcrm_Company WHERE CompanyName LIKE %LUX% OR PersonName LIKE %LUX% OR Country LIKE %LUX%
Internal error - an SQL exception occurred
SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%LUX% OR PersonName LIKE %LUX% OR Country LIKE %LUX%' at line 1
```

However this query works fine in MySQL Workbench

```
SELECT * FROM wcrm_Company WHERE CompanyName LIKE "%LUX%" OR PersonName LIKE "%LUX%" OR Country LIKE "%LUX%";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes around the strings, or you could escape the double quotes, but using single quotes is easier to read and maintain IMO

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM wcrm_Company 
                WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%"+search+"%' 
                OR PersonName LIKE '%"+search+"%' 
                OR Country LIKE '%"+search+"%'";
```